# Time not showing correctly in HighChart

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, datetime, highcharts

I am working with HighStock Charts.

In the DB I have UTC DateTime  '`2015-04-21 11:09:21.000`':

[image]

I am cnverting this to Custom Time Zone in my Code (Should + 5 Hours in this Case):

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(reading.dtUTCDateTime, assetCountryTimeZone);
```

[image]

As you can see below the Time in the View is correct: ie.

```
11:09 + 5 Hrs = 16:09
```

[image]

I then Convert the Array/List in Json:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    var avgCustomArray2 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(avgCustomArray2));

// Display first
        var re = /-?\d+/;
 for (var i = 0; i < avgCustomArray2.length; i++) {
                    var m = re.exec(avgCustomArray2[i].date);

                    if (i == 0) {
                        console.log(new Date(parseInt(m[0])));
                        console.log(parseInt(m[0]));
                    }

// Removed Code from here:

}

    </script>
```

And in the `Console.log()`

I get the correct DateTime:  `Tue Apr 21 2015 16:09:21 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`

and in milliseconds: `1429628961000`  Still (16:09) http://jsfiddle.net/3wux78tL/

So when I plot the Graph, I get the wrong time it is (15:09): Which is 1 hour less than the correct value

[image]

This is the HighChart Code setup:

```
 $("#container").highcharts("StockChart", {
                    chart: { zoomType: "x" },
                    rangeSelector: { enabled: false },
                    legend: { enabled: true },
                    yAxis: [
                        {
                            tickInterval: 0.5,
                            min: 0
                        }
                    ],
                    xAxis: [
                        {
                            title: { text: "Time " },
                            type: 'datetime'
                        }
                    ],
                    series: [
                        {
                            data: chartData,
                            tooltip: { valueDecimals: 2 }
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to turn off this setting on highchart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this: [Highcharts - time off by 1 hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812030/highcharts-time-off-by-1-hour)

Attempt to do:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        // timezoneOffset: +1,
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks that solved the issue. I was looking in the: xAxis options